# fixtures + sqlalchemy orm working example

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fixtures

i am trying to load data when running unit tests using the two python packages fixture and sqlalchemy.

i can't seem to find an example on how exactly to do this, however.

i ended up here but this couldn't get it to run:

https://fixture.googlecode.com/svn-history/r256/branches/sa_scoped_session/fixture/examples/db/sqlalchemy_examples.py

anyone have simple examples or references ?